# Mapping each http block to a specific Authentication Provider

Tags: spring-security

I would like to base my Spring Security configuration depending on the user's context path.  If the user goes against a url with http://path1/resource1 I would like to direct them to a specific authentication provider.  If they come in on http://path2/resource2 I would like to direct them to a different authentication provider.  These url paths are REST based web services calls so that's why they're stateless and not coming from a form.  Currently, all authentication providers get executed.  What is the best approach for this situation?  I'm using spring-security 3.1.0.M1.

```
<http pattern="/path1/**" create-session="stateless">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_VAR,ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <http-basic />      
</http>
<http pattern="/path2/**" create-session="stateless">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_VAR,ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <http-basic />      
</http>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="basicAuthenticationManager">
  <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="accountService">
    <security:password-encoder hash="sha"/>
  </security:authentication-provider>
  <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="accountService"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="basicProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager">
        <ref bean="basicAuthenticationManager" />
    </property>    
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <ref bean="basicProcessingEntryPoint" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="basicProcessingEntryPoint"
    class="com.yourpackage.web.util.CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="yourRealm" />
</bean>

<!-- Stateless RESTful service using Basic authentication -->   
<security:http pattern="/rest/**" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="basicProcessingEntryPoint">       
    <security:custom-filter ref="basicProcessingFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />     
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/new" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</security:http>

<!-- Additional filter chain for normal users, matching all other requests -->
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="permitAll" />      
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/signin" 
        authentication-failure-url="/signin?signin_error=1" 
        default-target-url="/" 
        always-use-default-target="true"/>      
    <security:logout />
</security:http>
```

I implemented the authentication entry point because I needed to send some special error codes in certain situations but you don't need to do so.

Comment: thanks for the response martincastell.  One thing that maybe you can clarify a bit is how are you mapping your rest http block to one authentication provider while mapping your form http block to a different authentication provider.  That is what I'm trying to achieve and its not clear to me in you example.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can define an authentication-manager reference in each http block:

```
<http pattern="/api/**" authentication-manager-ref="apiAccess">
    ...
</http>

<http auto-config = "true" authentication-manager-ref="webAccess">
    ...
</http>

<!-- Web authentication manager -->
<authentication-manager id="webAccess">
    <authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<!-- API authentication manager -->    
<authentication-manager id="apiAccess">
    <authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="developerService">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

This feature has been added in Spring Security 3.1.

Comment: Note use of `id` rather than `alias` for the `authentication-manager`. It seems that Spring Security can select the wrong authentication manager if you use `alias`.